# Find the limit in $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find

$$\lim_{z \to i} \frac{2z^4-2z^3+8z^2-2z+5}{z-i}$$

I have a feeling that this limit does not exist, because the numerator term for it is not factorizable in the field of complexes, try to test [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=factorize%202Power%5Bx%2C4%5D-2Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%2B8Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-2x%2B5&lang=es)

But the limit does not really refer to a case of zero over zero, since let us note that:

$$2\left(i\right)^4-2\left(i\right)^3+8\left(i\right)^2-2\left(i\right)+5=2-\left(-2i\right)-8-2i+5=-1$$

Perhaps it is useful to multiply by a convenient one to fix the denominator expression, any suggestions?

Comment: Certainly the limit $L$ doesn't exist as a complex number, because, if it did, then we would have $0\cdot L = -1$.  Is that the question?

Comment: @LSpice Sure, something like this

Comment: if you change the $5$   to $6$   there is a limit. So: where did you get the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial long division yields
$$f(z) = \frac{2z^4 - 2z^3 + 8z^2 - 2z + 5}{z-i} = 2z^3 - (2-2i)z^2 + (6-2i)z + 6i + \frac{1}{z-i},$$
so the limit of $f$, if it exists, must be equivalent to
$$4 + 8i - \lim_{z \to i} \frac{1}{z-i}.$$
Now it is straightforward to see that the limit of $f$ does not exist.

Comment: $-1$, not $+1$.  For these purposes, since you don't actually use the quotient in an essential way, the division isn't telling you any more useful information than the value of the numerator at $i$, which was already computed in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the numerator should be $  \left(  2 x^{4}  -2  x^{3}  + 8 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 6 \right)  : $
I use $x^2 + 1$   because $(x-i)(x+i) = x^2 + 1$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right)  \left( 0 \right)  -  \left( 1  \right)  \left( 1  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{confirming  GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right)  \left( 0 \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left( 1  \right)  =  \color{blue}{  \left(   -  x^{2}  - 1 \right)  } $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right) }   $$

Comment: I know the value was not $6$, but good description of that hypothetical case.